# How to get oracle TimeSpan column in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have a column with TimeSpan type in oracle, I need to define it in Entityframework,
I did like this :

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(p => p.DatBlock).HasColumnName("DATBLOCK").HasColumnType("DATETIME");
            }
```

I'm getting this error : schema specified is not valid.

Comment: What is the exact type in the Oracle table? TimeSpan is not a valid type. Also "schema specified is not valid" indicates some invalid schema name in your model. YOu should give more details on your class/database model + EF version (6, from what I see).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following conversion

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(e => e.DatBlock).HasConversion<DateTime>();
}
```